# UIBezierPath in tableViewCell conflicts border between cells

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController and that ViewController has a tableView. this tableView can have cells in four state, I need two of these have a dashed border UIView inside them and cus of this I used UIBazierPath az below:

```
private func setIconContainerViewBorder(dashed: Bool, _color: CGColor) {
    if dashed {
        let _border = CAShapeLayer()
        _border.lineDashPattern = [5, 4]
        _border.fillColor = nil
        _border.lineWidth = 2
        _border.strokeColor = _color
        _border.frame = self.iconContainerView.bounds
        _border.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.iconContainerView.bounds, cornerRadius: self.iconContainerView.frame.height / 2).cgPath
        self.iconContainerView.layer.addSublayer(_border)
    } else {
        self.iconContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = self.iconContainerView.frame.height / 2
        self.iconContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.iconContainerView.layer.borderColor = _color
    }
}
```

the problem is when I delete or add cells to tableview ( I go with present modally to another view controller and after dismissing that viewController and getting back to this viewController some cells border gets messed up, see below:

**picture1**

[image: Screen Shot]

**picture2**

[image: Screen Shot]

**picture3**

[image: Screen Shot].

I tested everything I can think of, reloading tableview, deleting rows and inserting again, but nothing works. can anyone help me plz?

Comment: Where do you call `setIconContainerViewBorder` from? (For example, do you call it from `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`?)  Also, what is the type of `self.iconContainerView`? Just a plain `UIView`, or a `UIImageView`, or some custom view class?

Comment: I have a nib and associated TableViewCell file, i call that function in didset property of cell.yea, its UIView, that contains an imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table view reuses cells. You add another `CAShapeLayer` every time a cell is reused and `dashed` is true. Those shape layers remain even when the cell is reused later for a non-dashed icon.

You should make a `UIView` subclass to handle the shape layer. `iconContainerView` should be an instance of that subclass, and have an instance variable referencing the shape layer.

Comment: So how can i remove that CAShapeLayer? And where should i keep that variable?

Comment: I think a dirty in hand solution can be using same tableViewCell with different ids every time, but I'm searching for a clean solution to feel better about my code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private func setIconContainerViewBorder(dashed: Bool, _color: CGColor) {
    if let _sublayers = self.iconContainerView.layer.sublayers {
        for _sublayer in _sublayers {
            if let _caShapeLayer = _sublayer as? CAShapeLayer {
                _caShapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    self.iconContainerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.iconContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 0

    if dashed {
        let _border = CAShapeLayer()
        _border.lineDashPattern = [5, 4]
        _border.fillColor = nil
        _border.lineWidth = 2
        _border.strokeColor = _color
        _border.frame = self.iconContainerView.bounds
        _border.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.iconContainerView.bounds, cornerRadius: self.iconContainerView.frame.height / 2).cgPath
        self.iconContainerView.layer.addSublayer(_border)
    } else {
        self.iconContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = self.iconContainerView.frame.height / 2
        self.iconContainerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.iconContainerView.layer.borderColor = _color
    }
}
```

Comment: this fixed my problem, thanx for helping @rob

Comment: but @rob 's answer is cleaner and I checked it as true answer